# SQL Projection Cost

Tags: sql

I have two tables A and B. These tables are linked via A.bid = B.id. Table A has 19 columns and table B has 10 columns. Both tables contain approximately 40,000 records.

I have been looking at the following 3 simple queries:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 FROM A, B
WHERE A.bid = B.id

-- Query 2
SELECT * FROM A

-- Query 3
SELECT Col1 FROM A
```

What I have found interesting is that Query 2 takes by far the longest to run, followed by Query 1 (the join) and the fastest being Query 3 (a more restrictive projection). All 3 queries return the same number of rows.

What is causing this behaviour? Why is the number of columns in the projection having such a large impact on performance? Of course I understand that the projection isn't free but I don't understand how a join (albeit with a more restricted projection) can run faster (a lot faster) than a simple `SELECT *` operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that using `SELECT *` returns ALL columns in the table.

This means that the database engine needs to read all columns and all rows, which in the case of your table A is a lot more. Also, this data needs to be transfered. So possibly a lot of network traffic too.

In SQL Server for example, you can create indexes with included columns( columns that is stored with the index, but does not influence the index itself).

This allows you to specify columns included with the index that you would use a lot in your selects. Not the actual joining or filtering columns, but rather additional columns used in display or calcuylations.

Now if you were to have a table, lets say `TABLE_A` with columns `A-Z`, with an INDEX on column `A,B,C` with included columns `D,E,F`

The Query

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE A = ?A
AND B = ?B
AND C = ?C
```

Would be able to use such an index.

Now if you were to run the query

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE A = ?A
AND B = ?B
AND C = ?C
```

The query engine would easily be able to identify the rows in question, but would still need to do a lookup to retrieve the column not included in the index.

Comment: I guess I under estimated the cost of the extra reads/network traffic. I was so focused on the cost of the key comparison in the join that I over looked these additional costs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because Sql engine is fetching all 19 columns to select, even if are not used in a condition, in Query 1 you have just 7 columns ans condition to carry about.